# Wordpress randomly starts saving a VERY LARGE amount of random junk into localstorage

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I dont know what is happening, there are only 4 instances of user made code that write into localstorage. None of them can come close to what is happening here (they all have hardcoded key strings anyways)

Here is a image of what is happening https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hv3F.png i was lucky to get this even because the whole console freezes

Comment: wowzers, check your plugins, what are you using? its def a plugin and not wordpress. try disabling each one to find the cause

Comment: it is something with Eleganth Themes Divi page builder plugin or Divi theme.